# How can I pass a variable from Terraform to ARM template and dynamic variable on run time in Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I'm creating CosmosDB with Terraform as I'm passing parameters to create cosmosDB with a excel sheet for automation and creating cosmosDB stuff like containers, storedprocedures and UDF with Azure ARM template.
My questions are-
1- How can I pass CosmosDB account name in ARM template from Terraform.
2- How can I pass no of containers or storedprocedures in ARM template on run time. For instance, my application team wants to create one container within same CosmosDb or sometimes they wants multiple containers within same DB so how can I pass no of containers on run time in ARM template.

Comment: Why the ARM template?  You can create containers with the azurerm provider.

Answer (score 0):

#2 isn't possible with ARM templates. If you want to data drive provisioning of Azure resources you need to use PS or CLI or Azure Management Libraries to do this.